# sitecore get list of protected items

Tags: sitecore

Does anyone know how to get a list of all the items protected (and unprotected them after) in sitecore?

I've googled around but I didn't find any relevant results.

Thanks in advance

This is what I have so far...

```cs
var homeItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath);
foreach (Item item in homeItem.Children)
{
   if (item.Locking.IsLocked())
    {
      //to do
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the item.Locking.IsLocked is not returning if the item is protected or not.

Comment: If you are in Sitecore Content Editor and click on Configure tab, you have the Attributes section where you can protect/unprotect the current item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you press protect or unprotect item this command is called:

```
item:togglereadonly
```

This is the part of the method who protect or unprotect item:

```
public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
{
    if (context.Items.Length != 1)
        return;
    Item obj = context.Items[0];
    obj.Editing.BeginEdit();
    obj.Appearance.ReadOnly = !obj.Appearance.ReadOnly;
    obj.Editing.EndEdit();
    Log.Audit((object) this, "Toggle read only: {0}, value: {1}", AuditFormatter.FormatItem(obj), MainUtil.BoolToString(obj.Appearance.ReadOnly));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution

```
var homeItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath);
foreach (Item item in homeItem.Children)
{
    if (item.Appearance.ReadOnly)
    {
       //stuff here
    }
}
```

Cheers